# Tetris implementing rotation

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am currently at the last stage of the Tetris Clone using SDL library, the only thing left is rotation. For each piece I have a separate class, and in order to move the pieces down I use a method:

```
void PieceZ::movePieceDown()
{
  drawBlock(x1,y1++);
  drawBlock(x2,y3++);
  drawBlock(x3,y3++);
  drawBlock(x4,y4++);
}
```

This method is called like that: `current->movePieceDown();` where `current` represents a pointer to the current piece. Now to rotate the piece I have another method:

```
void PieceZ::rotatePiece()
{
  drawBlock(newX1,newY2++);
  drawBlock(x2,y2);
  drawBlock(newX3,newY3++);
  drawBlock(newX4,newY4++);
}
```

New X and Y coordinates are calculated elsewhere, with x2 and y2 taken as the origin.
My question is how do I swap `current->movePieceDown()` with `current->rotatePiece()` while the piece is moving? Taking into acount that I am handling keyboard events in another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I am posting it just in case. Basically I removed the method `rotatePiece()`, instead of that I have a method that calculates the rotation independently of drawing:

```
void PieceZ::getRotation()
{
  newX1 = (y1-y2) + x2;
  newY1 = (x2-x1) + y2;

  newX3 = (y3-y2) + x2;
  newY3 = (x2-x3) + y2;

  newX4 = (y4-y2) + x2;
  newY4 = (x2-x4) + y2;

  x1 = newX1;
  x3 = newX3;
  x4 = newX4;

  y1 = newY1;
  y3 = newY3;
  y4 = newY4;
}
```

`new` values are set to 0 initially, and every time a user presses a button on the keyboard this method gets called, it calculates the new rotation in `new` and assigns it to `x` and `y` values. Which gives you a 90 degree counter clockwise rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could store four different pre-defined rotations and swap amongst them.

Comment: That's true. But that would envolve having hard coded arrays instead of coordinates.